# How to configure Neo4j sink instances with Kafka and neo4j-streams

Tags: neo4j, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I'm setting up two instances of neo4j (source and sink) with neo4j-streams plugin and Kafka between.

I've red [official documentation](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-streams/) and [article on medium](https://medium.com/neo4j/a-new-neo4j-integration-with-apache-kafka-6099c14851d2) how to set up such cluster, but I cannot get sink instance work.

I'm using following docker-compose

```
version: '3'
services:
  neo4j-source:
    image: neo4j:3.4
    hostname: neo4j-source
    container_name: neo4j-source
    ports:
      - "7474:7474"
      - "7687:7687"
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    volumes:
      - ./plugins:/plugins
    environment:
      NEO4J_AUTH: neo4j/source
      NEO4J_dbms_logs_debug_level: DEBUG
      NEO4J_kafka_zookeeper_connect: zookeeper:12181
      NEO4J_kafka_bootstrap_servers: kafka:19092

  neo4j-sink:
    image: neo4j:3.4
    hostname: neo4j-sink
    container_name: neo4j-sink
    ports:
      - "7475:7474"
      - "7688:7687"
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    volumes:
      - ./plugins:/plugins
    environment:
      NEO4J_AUTH: neo4j/sink
      NEO4J_dbms_logs_debug_level: DEBUG
      NEO4J_kafka_zookeeper_connect: zookeeper:12181
      NEO4J_kafka_bootstrap_servers: kafka:19092
      NEO4J_streams_sink_topic_cypher_neo4j:  "WITH event.value.payload AS payload, event.value.meta AS meta
        FOREACH (ignoreMe IN CASE WHEN payload.type = 'node' AND meta.operation <> 'deleted' and payload.after.labels[0] = 'Question' THEN [1] ELSE [] END |
          MERGE (n:Question{neo_id: toInteger(payload.id)}) ON CREATE
            SET n += payload.after.properties
        )
        FOREACH (ignoreMe IN CASE WHEN payload.type = 'node' AND meta.operation <> 'deleted' and payload.after.labels[0] = 'Answer' THEN [1] ELSE [] END |
          MERGE (n:Answer{neo_id: toInteger(payload.id)}) ON CREATE
            SET n += payload.after.properties
        )
        FOREACH (ignoreMe IN CASE WHEN payload.type = 'node' AND meta.operation <> 'deleted' and payload.after.labels[0] = 'User' THEN [1] ELSE [] END |
          MERGE (n:User{neo_id: toInteger(payload.id)}) ON CREATE
            SET n += payload.after.properties
        )
        FOREACH (ignoreMe IN CASE WHEN payload.type = 'node' AND meta.operation <> 'deleted' and payload.after.labels[0] = 'Tag' THEN [1] ELSE [] END |
          MERGE (n:Tag{neo_id: toInteger(payload.id)}) ON CREATE
            SET n += payload.after.properties
        )
        FOREACH (ignoreMe IN CASE WHEN payload.type = 'relationship' AND meta.operation <> 'deleted' and payload.label = 'ANSWERS' THEN [1] ELSE [] END |
          MERGE (s:Answer{neo_id: toInteger(payload.start.id)})
          MERGE (e:Question{neo_id: toInteger(payload.end.id)})
          CREATE (s)-[:ANSWERS{neo_id: toInteger(payload.id)}]->(e)
        )
        FOREACH (ignoreMe IN CASE WHEN payload.type = 'relationship' AND meta.operation <> 'deleted' and payload.label = 'TAGGED' THEN [1] ELSE [] END |
          MERGE (s:Question{neo_id: toInteger(payload.start.id)})
          MERGE (e:Tag{neo_id: toInteger(payload.end.id)})
          CREATE (s)-[:TAGGED{neo_id: toInteger(payload.id)}]->(e)
        )
        FOREACH (ignoreMe IN CASE WHEN payload.type = 'relationship' AND meta.operation <> 'deleted' and payload.label = 'PROVIDED' THEN [1] ELSE [] END |
          MERGE (s:User{neo_id: toInteger(payload.start.id)})
          MERGE (e:Answer{neo_id: toInteger(payload.end.id)})
          CREATE (s)-[:PROVIDED{neo_id: toInteger(payload.id)}]->(e)
        )
        FOREACH (ignoreMe IN CASE WHEN payload.type = 'relationship' AND meta.operation <> 'deleted' and payload.label = 'ASKED' THEN [1] ELSE [] END |
          MERGE (s:User{neo_id: toInteger(payload.start.id)})
          MERGE (e:Question{neo_id: toInteger(payload.end.id)})
          CREATE (s)-[:ASKED{neo_id: toInteger(payload.id)}]->(e)
        )"

  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "12181:12181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 12181

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    hostname: kafka
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
      - "19092:19092"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:12181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:19092
```

When I'm creating a new `User` node in source neo4j

```
CREATE (n:User{name: "John Smith"})
```

I see message in Kafka:

```
{"payload":{"id":"0","before":null,"after":{"properties":{"name":"John Smith"},"labels":["User"]},"type":"node"},"meta":{"timestamp":1554075819827,"username":"neo4j","txId":4,"txEventId":0,"txEventsCount":1,"operation":"created","source":{"hostname":"neo4j-source"}},"schema":{"properties":[],"constraints":null}}
```

And logs from docker instances:

```
neo4j-source    | 2019-03-31 23:43:39.876+0000 DEBUG Trying to send a transaction event with txId 4 and txEventId 0 to kafka
neo4j-source    | 2019-03-31 23:43:40.167+0000 DEBUG Sent record in partition 0 offset 0 data neo4j key size 3
neo4j-sink      | 2019-03-31 23:43:40.228+0000 DEBUG Reading data from topic neo4j, with data [{payload={id=0, before=null, after={properties={name=John Smith}, labels=[User]}, type=node}, meta={timestamp=1554075819827, username=neo4j, txId=4, txEventId=0, txEventsCount=1, operation=created, source={hostname=neo4j-source}}, schema={properties=[], constraints=null}}]
neo4j-sink      | 2019-03-31 23:43:40.236+0000 DEBUG Processing 1 events, for topic neo4j with query: UNWIND {events} AS event WITH event.value.payload AS payload, event.value.meta AS meta FOREACH (ignoreMe IN CASE WHEN payload.type = 'node' AND meta.operation <> 'deleted' and payload.after.labels[0] = 'Question' THEN [1] ELSE [] END | MERGE (n:Question{neo_id: toInteger(payload.id)}) ON CREATE SET n += payload.after.properties ) FOREACH (ignoreMe IN CASE WHEN payload.type = 'node' AND meta.operation <> 'deleted' and payload.after.labels[0] = 'Answer' THEN [1] ELSE [] END | MERGE (n:Answer{neo_id: toInteger(payload.id)}) ON CREATE SET n += payload.after.properties ) FOREACH (ignoreMe IN CASE WHEN payload.type = 'node' AND meta.operation <> 'deleted' and payload.after.labels[0] = 'User' THEN [1] ELSE [] END | MERGE (n:User{neo_id: toInteger(payload.id)}) ON CREATE SET n += payload.after.properties ) FOREACH (ignoreMe IN CASE WHEN payload.type = 'node' AND meta.operation <> 'deleted' and payload.after.labels[0] = 'Tag' THEN [1] ELSE [] END | MERGE (n:Tag{neo_id: toInteger(payload.id)}) ON CREATE SET n += payload.after.properties ) FOREACH (ignoreMe IN CASE WHEN payload.type = 'relationship' AND meta.operation <> 'deleted' and payload.label = 'ANSWERS' THEN [1] ELSE [] END | MERGE (s:Answer{neo_id: toInteger(payload.start.id)}) MERGE (e:Question{neo_id: toInteger(payload.end.id)}) CREATE (s)-[:ANSWERS{neo_id: toInteger(payload.id)}]->(e) ) FOREACH (ignoreMe IN CASE WHEN payload.type = 'relationship' AND meta.operation <> 'deleted' and payload.label = 'TAGGED' THEN [1] ELSE [] END | MERGE (s:Question{neo_id: toInteger(payload.start.id)}) MERGE (e:Tag{neo_id: toInteger(payload.end.id)}) CREATE (s)-[:TAGGED{neo_id: toInteger(payload.id)}]->(e) ) FOREACH (ignoreMe IN CASE WHEN payload.type = 'relationship' AND meta.operation <> 'deleted' and payload.label = 'PROVIDED' THEN [1] ELSE [] END | MERGE (s:User{neo_id: toInteger(payload.start.id)}) MERGE (e:Answer{neo_id: toInteger(payload.end.id)}) CREATE (s)-[:PROVIDED{neo_id: toInteger(payload.id)}]->(e) ) FOREACH (ignoreMe IN CASE WHEN payload.type = 'relationship' AND meta.operation <> 'deleted' and payload.label = 'ASKED' THEN [1] ELSE [] END | MERGE (s:User{neo_id: toInteger(payload.start.id)}) MERGE (e:Question{neo_id: toInteger(payload.end.id)}) CREATE (s)-[:ASKED{neo_id: toInteger(payload.id)}]->(e) )
neo4j-sink      | 2019-03-31 23:43:41.975+0000 DEBUG Query statistics:
neo4j-sink      | <Nothing happened>
```

And, as you can see in logs, nothing created in sink.

I've tried simple queries, but cannot deliver any node in sink neo4j. How sink `streams.sink.topic.cypher` query should be changed? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like [documentation](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-streams/#_consumer) contains an error in consumer config, events from kafka topic has no `value` in JSON.

Instead of

```
      ...
      NEO4J_streams_sink_topic_cypher_neo4j:  "WITH event.value.payload AS payload, event.value.meta AS meta
        FOREACH (ignoreMe IN CASE WHEN payload.type = 'node' AND meta.operation <> 'deleted' and payload.after.labels[0] = 'Question' THEN [1] ELSE [] END |
      ...
```

Should be

```
      ...
      NEO4J_streams_sink_topic_cypher_neo4j:  "WITH event.payload AS payload, event.meta AS meta
        FOREACH (ignoreMe IN CASE WHEN payload.type = 'node' AND meta.operation <> 'deleted' and payload.after.labels[0] = 'Question' THEN [1] ELSE [] END |
      ...
```

And it works fine, logs:

```
neo4j-sink      | 2019-04-01 21:21:09.263+0000 DEBUG Query statistics:
neo4j-sink      | Nodes created: 1
neo4j-sink      | Properties set: 2
neo4j-sink      | Labels added: 1
```